# Caching twitter widget with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to cache twitter feeds using razor syntax, and I'm trying to incorporate that using  @Html.Action. Upon running the code, the compiler error says that :

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can someone tell me if I am missing some sort of @directory?

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html> 
<body>
<div>
@{
var user = Dnn.User;
var twitterName=user.Profile.GetPropertyValue("Twitter");
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(twitterName)){
    twitterName="tdsb";
}
}


@functions{
public class MyController : Controller
[OutputCache(VaryByParam="none", Duration=60)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModel.Message=Twitter.Profile(twitterName).ToString();
    return View();
}
}
@Html.Action("Index")

}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My apologies dbaseman, I'm a little confused, isn't actionresult in the controller class. Could you explain a little what you mean?

Comment: I'm also missing a bracket for public class MyController, but after fixing it still gives the same issue

Comment: Yes, it's in the controller class, but why is the controller class embedded in the view?  I don't see how it makes sense to try it that way ...

Comment: I can only use one script file for the entire process -- I'm guessing what you're asking is why am I putting everything in the view file?

Comment: yes ... I'm not understanding why it's necessary ... but assuming it is, maybe try including ActionResult's namespace?  `@using System.Web.Mvc`

Comment: Thanks dbaseman, but it still reads the original error, I'm going to keep trying alternatives. As for why it's necessary, the razor host runs on dnn modules and is structured this way